# I tried dvc checkout and ran into an error?

Tags: git, amazon-s3, dvc

I have a following structure for my project (see example at the bottom) . I craeted a branch one and initialized dvc in the subdirectory , via

```
cd projectA && dvc init --subdir
```

for now, i'm working with projectA only, I created a branch, and ran following steps

step 1 .

```
dvc remote add -d awsstorage s3://mlops-artifacts
dvc remote add s3cache s3://mlops-artifacts/cache
dvc config cache.s3 s3cache

git add projectA/.dvc/config

git commit -m "configure remote storage and cache"

git push
```

dataset folder contains csv data for trainign and output folder contains model.tar file - output of the training

step 2 -

```
dvc add --external awsstorage s3://mlops-artifacts/dataset
dvc add --external awsstorage s3://mlops-artifacts/output

git add projectA/dataset.dvc projectA/output.dvc

git commit -m "configure data and model output"

git push
```

I created another branch (branch-2) , made some changes to the  input data and uploaded to the same se location and ran the training.  after training, model output is dumped to same s3 path. so to capture these new changes . i ran step 1 and step 2 above in the new branch.

now when i tried to do a git checkout of the first branch and then dvc checkout , so that i can go to the previous version of data and model output and i got following error

error

```
Error: checkout failed for following targets:
s3://mlops-artifacts/dataset/training.csv
s3://mlops-artifacts/output/model.tar

Is your cache up to date?
<https://error.dvc.org/missing-files>
```

project structure

```
myproject
-- projectA
   -- .dvc
   ...
-- ProjectB
   -- .dvc
   ...
```

Comment: You might need to run `dvc push` along with `git push`. Could you try that please?

Comment: @Shcheklein - thanks I will try that but my understanding was , when you run this command -  dvc add —external , with external flag , you don’t need dvc push

Comment: @Scheklein - when i try dvc push, i get an warning : some of the cache files do not exist neither locally nor on remote . missing cache files:  name : s3://mlops-artifacts/dataset/training.csv, etag: ed0392mcn433343.... also , when i do dvc status , i get, training.csv.dvc:
changed outs:
not in cache:                                mlops-artifacts/dataset/training.csv. how do i debug this. this setup workflow worked for me once, i'm not sure what happened.

Comment: can you start from scratch please? if feels there is already a discrepancy in what you have in your `.dvc` files locally and what files are actually present in the `s3://mlops-artifacts` bucket. Try to do `dvc add ...` + `git commit` + `dvc push` together, w/o running checkout, pull, etc.

Comment: @Shcheklein - here is my set up , https://gitlab.com/headfoot/mlops/-/blob/main/README.md. this has worked for me but not sure why this is not working anymore. one question , when dvc pushes cache data to s3 bucket, does it uses http or https ? how does it actually copy data from data folder to cache folder